# jquery append class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to reproduce this html using jquery on a click event.

```
<div class="comments_action_207">
   <div class="list_item_comments list_item_comments_207">
      <div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

before the click event I have the following html:

```
<div class="comments_action_207"></div>
```

So I need to add this inside the previous code

```
<div class="list_item_comments list_item_comments_207"><div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.comments_action_207').click(function() {
        var num = this.className.split('_').pop();
        $('<div/>',{'class':'list_item_comments list_item_comments_' + num})
            .append('<div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div>')
            .appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

The click is assigned specifically to the `comments_action_207` element. I assume you want to assign to others as well.

This will take the number from the end of the class, create the new elements, adding on the number where needed, and will append the result to the `comments_action_207` element.

The resulting HTML will be:

```
<div class="comments_action_207">
    <div class="list_item_comments list_item_comments_207">
        <div class="comment_separator">text goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got this (dont need the click event and num) $('<div/>',{'class':'list_item_comments list_item_comments_214'})
            .append('<div class="comment_separator">test</div>')
            .appendTo(this);
but dont work

Comment: @Yannick - Are you saying that you're not in a click handler? What is triggering the code? If you're not in a handler, but it is just running when the page loads, change `.appendTo(this)` to `.appendTo('.comments_action_214')`.

Answer (score 1):

you want to set the html code you want to add as a string datatype in a variable in jquery. then in your click function handler, set the html content of the div to the variable. in jquery it would look something like this. (assuming jquery is loaded before this script is ran).

http://docs.jquery.com/Html documentation for how to get and set html in selectors with jquery.

```
//jquery code:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stringToAdd = "<div class='list_item_comments list_item_comments_207'><div class='comment_separator'>text goes here</div></div>"

    $('.comments_action_207').click(function(){
       $(this).html(stringToAdd);
     });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Make code monospace (and therefore legible) by enclosing it in backticks ` or indenting it by four spaces. Great answer, though!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow so I just typed the code with manual tabbing

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".comments_action_207").empty(); // clear the div off, if you do not want to retain old values

$(".comments_action_207").append("<div class='list_item_comments list_item_comments_207'><div class='comment_separator'>text goes here</div></div>");
```